# Laravel insertOrIgnore inserting duplicate rows and empty rows during a CSV file upload

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `companies` table. Each company has a company_id with a unique constraint.

```
$table->string('company_id', 9)->unique();
```

I'm uploading a CSV file with 1M rows containing a single column of these unique company_id.

I'm aware the file has MANY duplicate rows so not even half of the rows should be inserted because I'm using Laravel's insertOrIgnore method. Here's my CSV upload method :

```
public function csvUpload(Request $request)
  {
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'csv' => 'required|file',
    ]);

    $path = $request->csv->store('temp');
    
    $input = base_path() . Storage::url('app/' . $path);
            
    $handle = fopen($input, 'r');
    
    // Push the data into an array
    $company_ids = [];
    $rows = 0;
    $now = now();
    $inserted = 0;

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9)) !== FALSE) {

      $company_ids[] = [
        'company_id' => $data[0],
        'created_at' => $now,
        'updated_at' => $now,
      ];
      $rows++;

      if ($rows >= 1000) {
        
        // Insert company_ids into companies table
        $inserted += Company::insertOrIgnore($company_ids);

        unset($company_ids); // unset to avoid memory issues
        $company_ids = [];
        $rows = 0;
      }

    }

    // Insert remaining company_ids (those when no more rows but total rows less then 1000)
    $inserted += Company::insertOrIgnore($company_ids);
    
    // close the stored file
    fclose($handle);
        
    // delete the file
    Storage::delete($path);
    
    return redirect()->route('companies.index')
    ->with('message', $inserted . ' new company_ids uploaded');
  }
```

However, this is saving all rows, including the duplicate ones, and also inserting rows with an empty company_id every two rows.

I'm using Laravel 9 with MySQL.

I'm thinking it could come from how the CSV is parsed or the fact that i chunk the data before inserting it but cannot find the issue here.

EDIT 1:
In parallel, I have queue workers attaching companies to another model. This other model has a company_id attribute so I'm using firstOrCreate in that job. Like: find the company with this company_id or create it. More empty rows are being created as I speak so those jobs must be the ones creating the empty rows but doesn't explain why the CSV upload inserted duplicate rows however.

EDIT 2:
there seems to be an issue with these jobs described above. I deleted the rows with an empty company_id but, as more rows are being inserted to the table because of the queue workers, I see that an id is always skipped. One row has 2955265, the next has id 2955267.

Comment: Maybe you should show us the code that creates the table

Comment: As you only seem to have a 'company_id` and 2 dates in the file I assume the duplication is on the `'company_id`. Did you set that column as unique?

Comment: yes, it is unique (see top of my question). I could show you the migration but it has nothing special, bunch of different columns and that company_id column with a unique constraint.

Comment: Then duplicates are just impossible :) So either you or the Migrations is wrong. Shall we open a book on which one is most likely?

Comment: @RiggsFolly haha, I thought this site was no chitchat so I'll ignore your sarcasm and welcome other inputs. But thanks anyway

Comment: It may seems a little sarcastic, but really, what other options are there. If the `company_id` is truely set to UNIQUE then MySQL **cannot create a duplicate**, even if you decide to ignore the duplicate errors. You could try changing the call to a normal INSERT and see what errors are actually generated, or maybe there wont be any, or maybe they might throw a little more light onto the subject

Comment: Did you try checking the Schema with `phpMyAdmin` or `MySQL Workbench`

Comment: Ok, no offence taken. I made a `DESCRIBE companies;`on my production server after you pointed a missing index could be the issue and yes, the column doesn't have the index. Very weird because it has it locally, my migration is correct. Do you think I should make a new migration to change the column index OR change it directly in production from the mysql cli?

Comment: Totally up to you, I would personally make sure the migration was correct.